# Understanding dnorm and geom_density

Tags: r, ggplot2, normal-distribution, probability-density

```
x <- seq(-4, 4, length.out = 100)
data.frame(x,  f = dnorm(x)) %>%
     ggplot(aes(x, f)) +
     geom_line()
```

imho, this should give the exact same plot as this:

```
x <- seq(-4, 4, length.out = 100)
data.frame(x,  f = dnorm(x)) %>%
   ggplot() +
   geom_density(aes(x))
```

How come it doesn't?

Comment: Why should plotting a line give the same thing as estimating the density of some data and then plotting that?

Comment: Got it. 

        x <- seq(-4, 4, length.out = 100)

creates a constantly distributed variable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are probably looking for `stat_function`

```
x <- seq(-4, 4, length.out = 100)
data.frame(x,  f = dnorm(x)) %>%
     ggplot(aes(x, f)) +
     geom_line() + 
     stat_function(fun=dnorm, geom="line", col=2, lty=2)
```